# PHP echo not displaying in HTML

Tags: php, html, echo

I'm new to PHP and I'm following the PHP tut on w3schools. I am using Eclipse's latest IDE version (3.6 I think). for my script helloDriver.php it functions fine when ran as a php script. it doesn't on my html file especially when I use a similar method to the example from w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_forms.asp

This would be my code for helloDriver.php:

```
<html>
<body>
go
<?php
    echo "giga";
?>
power rangers
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code for homepage.html

```
<html>
<body>
Hey
<form action="helloDriver.php">
<input type="submit />
</body>
</html>
```

"Hey" and "go" both display so I know that the php file is being called but I don't know why the echo command doesn't.

Even before this I copied line by line with what the w3schools example was with the exception of welcome.php since that is helloDriver.php

How I access the html file is double clicking it since Eclipse doesn't have any options to run the program. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you view source do you see the php call? I'm thinking your web server is not set up to interpret the php.

Comment: step one w3schools is rubbish

Answer (score 3):

Where are these files hosted?  I'm guessing your web server (e.g., Apache or IIS) isn't configured to run `.php` files through the PHP interpreter, but instead is serving them statically.

Comment: That would be it. I have no server or anything. It is simpyl me double clicking the html file and seeing what shows

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a really hard time working out what your question is.

Some problems with your HTML file are:

- You're missing the closing `</form>` tag
- You haven't closed the quotes on your submit button.

The complete markup should probably be more like

```
<form action="helloDriver.php">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Another thing that might be the problem, you need to access the PHP scripts through a web server. Have you installed something like XAMPP?

Comment: no i haven't. not sure what that is. as I said before. I am new to the extreme to PHP. I'll look into what what XAMPP is.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. Thank you guys for help and thanks for suggesting XAMPP. 
Installed it from this link (googling XAMPP works just as well):
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1173

It was straightforward and easy to set up. Set the destination to install on the C: drive. Also stumbled across this tut vid on how to set up a PHP project using PHP, XAMPP, and Eclipse:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfHEmZXJLgw

I should be able to figure things through trial and error. Thanks again!

Comment: A piece of advise do not rely much on w3Schools tutorials. See this http://w3fools.com for some php tutorial read first the php manual here http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php